# Oracle: Is it possible to filter out duplicates only when they appear in succession?

Tags: oracle, duplicates

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have a table that holds itinerary information for drivers.  There will be times when the itinerary seems to have the same stop (but is several days apart). I'd like to be able to query the table and filter out any record where the address is the same AND the dates are consecutive.

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks again,
josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with tst as(
    select timestamp '2020-08-01 00:00:00' dt, '123 street' loc from dual
    union all
    select timestamp '2020-08-01 00:00:00', '89 street' from dual
    union all
    select timestamp '2020-08-02 00:00:00', '456 airport' from dual
    union all
    select timestamp '2020-08-04 00:00:00', '456 airport' from dual
    union all
    select timestamp '2020-08-05 00:00:00', '67 street' from dual
    union all
    select timestamp '2020-08-06 00:00:00', '89 street' from dual
    union all
    select timestamp '2020-08-07 00:00:00', '123 street' from dual
)
select dt, loc
from (
    select dt, loc, nvl(lag(loc) over(order by dt), 'FIRST_ROW') prev_loc
    from tst
) where loc <> prev_loc;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64df303272817cf4d054d6b877fd4432)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `Tabibitosan method` which assign consecutive rows a group number and then count number of rows per group.(found in asktom website).

```
with test_data as(
    select date'2020-08-01' dt, '123 street' loc from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-01', '89 street' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-02', '456 airport' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-04', '456 airport' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-05', '67 street' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-06', '89 street' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-07', '123 street' from dual
)
select max(dt),loc
from
(
select t.*
  ,row_number() over (order by dt) -
   row_number() over (partition by loc order by dt) grp
  from test_data t
)
group by grp,loc
having count(*) > 1;
```

Another approach using `match_recognize` available from 12c onwards.patter used `{1,}` says repeated one or more times

more to learn `match_recognize` [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1)

```
with test_data as(
    select date'2020-08-01' dt, '123 street' loc from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-01', '89 street' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-02', '456 airport' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-04', '456 airport' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-05', '67 street' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-06', '89 street' from dual
    union all
    select date '2020-08-07', '123 street' from dual
)
select * 
  from test_data
match_recognize (
  order by dt
  all rows per match
  pattern (equal{1,})
  define 
    equal as loc = prev(loc)
);
```

Playground: [Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72dccb0a16f9840fca55c8212adfa15b)